# Single page site link color toggling Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a single page micro site I am building and all the content is on one page.  I am using anchor tags to jump to specific sections of the site.  What I am trying to achieve is a cross browser solution that will make my link color the same as :hover and stay until another link is clicked which then in return would make previously clicked link go back to normal state.

Please help!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BR4W/1/)

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="selected">Test 1<a>
<a href="#" class="">Test 2<a>​
```

CSS

```
a.selected {
    color: pink;
}​
```

JavaScript (using jQuery)

```
$("a").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) { return; }

    $("a").removeClass("selected");        
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});​
```

In this example I use all the anchor tags on the page. It is probably better to select them more specifically using classes.

Add the following line of html before you run the code above, but put is a low as possible in your page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using cufon.  This does not work with cufon.  Do you by chance know a workaround?

Comment: Any idea on how to get this to work with font-replacement like Cufon?

Comment: @RobertTaylor Well there are multiple solutions. 1: you can add jQuery to the page, load jQuery before Cufon and use jQuery instead $ (look for SO answers how use both). 2: Don't use Cufon. 3: Rewrite the code above into plain JavaScript, which requires a lot more code.

Comment: No it is not working :(  I have jquery loaded before cufon

code before /head:
<style type="text/css">
h1 a.selected {
    color: pink;
}​
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("h1 a").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) { return; }

    $("h1 a").removeClass("selected");        
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});​
</script>

Comment: My html for links:
<div class="home-link"><h1><a class="selected" href="#home">Home</a></h1></div>
    <div class="hiw-link"><h1><a class="" href="#howitworks">How It Works</a></h1></div>
    <div class="faq-link"><h1><a class="" href="#faq">Faq</a></h1></div>
    <div class="prize-link"><h1><a class="" href="#prizes">Prizes</a></h1></div>
    <div class="media-link"><h1><a class="" href="#media">Media</a></h1></div>
    <div class="rules-link"><h1><a class="" href="#rules">Rules</a></h1></div>

Comment: @RobertTaylor Try using the word 'jQuery' instead of '$' (other name for the same thing). Cufon is using $ also and if you load jQuery first, Cufon will take over the $ sign. I updated the Fiddle in my answer using the same html you have now.